# Rows to Columns by id Hive Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data by users and services used by date, the problem I have is that I need the dates as columns by p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 , I can not created columns by an specific product as they may adopt them in different order, I have a marker that shows the concat of the products by the order they adopt them, but need to analyze the time it took them to adop a new one.

I have the following data Table:

| ID | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | phone | 2022-01-01 |
| 01 | cell | 2022-02-01 |
| 01 | water | 2022-03-01 |

and I need to get the following:

| ID | P1 | P2 | P3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-01 |

Comment: what do you mean by "as they may adopt them in different order"? do you only want a maximum of 3 date columns? should p1 always be the earliest date? (and p3 the latest date?) - some more information would help. Also: have you searched for "pivot" or "conditional aggregates"? **What version of MySQL? (this is important)**

Comment: the data is for used services so you can star using Phone, and then Cell and then move to Water, or enter by Cell, then Phone, or just use Water, there are several services, I add 3 just as an example, the data table that I have as the ID, product and the first date they used it in order, and yes P1 is earliest and PX is the last one used. no I haven't but will.

Comment: Because date order is important to your solution it is imperative you tell us which version of MySQL you are using. Version 8+ has a function **row_number()** with the clause **over()** to solve for the date order - but if using an earlier version sorting columns by date is more difficult. By the way: Why is "Hive" mentioned in the question title?

Comment: The table is sorted by Id and date (desc), I'm using jupiter notebooks that uses an instance of hive-tahoe to run mysql queries, and I have no idea what version it uses or how to get it.

Comment: `select version();` will return the version number of MySQL.